# Could not resolve vimeo.stag for project

Tags: azure-java-sdk

I keep getting this when running mvn clean install

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project tomtom: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sample:tomtom:jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact com.vimeo.stag:stag-library:jar:1.0.0 in azure-sdk (https://github.com/azure/azure-sdk-for-java) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Comment: Please provide your code by removing sensitive information to check the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you are getting due to the ***version incompatibility*** of spring boot application and the dependency.

***This could be because the artifact `com.vimeo.stag`  is not available in the repository or Maven is not able to access the repository.***

- Try using the latest version of the dependency which is compatible with the maven version you are using.
- Check if you have included the below dependency in the application and also required maven dependencies in pom.xml.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimeo.stag</groupId>
    <artifactId>stag-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

*As an alternative, run your application in IntelliJ IDE and check.*

- `mvn clean install` generally deletes the previous compilations, freshly builds and packages the application.
- As it is typically used with Maven, whatever the packages you are having in your projects must be compatible with the maven version.

[image]

Comment: Exactly, com.vimeo.stag is not available in mvn repo. It is available in spring milestone. Check the following: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/35408